# Can't parse JSON in ROBLOX Lua

Tags: json, lua, roblox

I am making a module script that runs another module if the player who called it is a string in a JSON object.

I get this error:

```lua
Can't parse JSON
-- Stack Begin
-- Script 'Model.MainModule', Line 8 - function load
-- Stack End
```

Code:

```lua
local module = {}

function module.load(plr)
    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    
    local decoded = HttpService:JSONDecode('{ players: ["HiroTDM999", "mrhotmadm"] }')

    for i, v in pairs(decoded.players) do
        if v == plr.Name then
            require(6380716368).load() -- runs another module (no json in it)
        end
    end
end

return module
```

Comment: @osekmedia yes thank you.

Comment: LOL Glad that worked.

Comment: yeah lol, I just need to figure out the looping now.

Comment: Try ipairs(decoded.players) in the loop

Comment: If you're not using the i you can do something like `for _, v in ipairs(decoded.players) do`

Comment: Yes, `ipairs` worked. Sadly it took me more time to respond because my file did not save, so I had to type out all the scripts again. Anyways thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is invalid, you need to wrap players in double quotes.

```
local module = {}

function module.load(plr)
    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    
    local decoded = HttpService:JSONDecode('{ "players": ["HiroTDM999", "mrhotmadm"] }')

    for i, v in pairs(decoded.players) do
        if v == plr.Name then
            require(6380716368).load() -- runs another module (no json in it)
        end
    end
end

return module
```

Comment: thanks, will accept this as an answer in 2 mins.